# Unused arguments while renaming columns from dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

[image: sample picture of my workflow and error message]

Hi all,
I am trying to rename the columns from the data frame (protein_df). As from here, the columns 'id' and 'Intensity' are shown to be located inside the data frame. However, the error message indicates that the argument to rename columns is unused. Does anyone have an idea of how this could happen?

Thanks!

Comment: The `dplyr` syntax looks OK. There might be function name conflict with other loaded packages. You can try using `{conflicted}` package to resolve the name conflict. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/06/conflicted/

Answer (score 6):

When you have that type of "unexplainable" error for `dplyr` functions, it is usually because there is a conflict between different libraries.  So use `dplyr::rename`  and it should be good.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to post your code as something that's copy/pastable text, you can format using backticks.

That error message means that the first arguments in `rename()` don't exist. I'm not sure if this is your goal, but my best guess is that you have the rename arguments backwards. Judging from the first print of your dataframe `head(protien_df)`, `id` and `intensity` are already the column names, so they need to go first in your `rename()`:

```
protein_df %>%
  rename(Intensity = Protien_intensity,
         id = Protien_group_IDs)
```

You can still pipe in the `rename()` bit to your `read_tsv` and save it to that df.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the base and dplyr library together this may happen, I figured out the solution for this. Addition of dplyr:: will help you.

protein_df %>% dplyr::rename(Intensity = Protien_intensity, id = Protein_group_IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with SD, the function 'rename' conflicts with other functions with the same func name in other packages, so designating the exact package where ur rename func is from might be useful.
Also, the grammar of the 2nd arg in func rename is'new_name = old_name', so try:

```
protein_df <- dplyr::rename(.,Protien_intensity=Intensity, Protein_group_IDs=id )
```